# How to apply different way of rendering for the parent element and the nested subrows

Tags: react-table

I'm using [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table), how can I apply two different ways of rendering one for the parent Element and other for the subRows.

For the parent element I want to display a single value. But for the sub rows I want to display an input to change them along with their values.

```
Cell: row => <span>Mid<input /></span>
```

I did this for the column but It also overrides the render way of the parent element. The parent element should only display the value not also the input.

As seen in the screenshot below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I went through the documentation. and looks there is no ideal way to apply this.
did you consider managing this via CSS

Cell: row => Mid

```
td:first-child input {
  display: none;
}
```